# How to modify the filename in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have 3 text files.I want to modify the file name of those files using for loop  as below .

Please find the files which I have

1234.xml

333.xml

cccc.xml

Output:

1234_R.xml

333_R.xml

cccc_R.xml

Answer (score 1):

Just basic unix command `mv` work both on move and rename

```
mv 1234.xml 1234_R.xml
```

If you want do it by a large amount, do like this:

```
[~/bash/rename]$ touch 1234.xml 333.xml cccc.xml
[~/bash/rename]$ ls
1234.xml  333.xml  cccc.xml
[~/bash/rename]$ L=`ls *.xml`
[~/bash/rename]$ for x in $L; do mv $x ${x%%.*}_R.xml; done
[~/bash/rename]$ ls
1234_R.xml  333_R.xml  cccc_R.xml
[~/bash/rename]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your distribution, you can use `rename`:

```
rename 's/(.*)(\.xml)/$1_R$2/' *.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *for* loop to iterate over a list of words (e.g. with the list of file names returned by `ls`) with the (bash) syntax:

```
for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
```

Then use `mv source dest` to rename each file.

One nice trick here, is to use `basename`, which strips directory and suffix from filenames (e.g. `basename 333.xml` will just return `333`).

If you put all this together, the following should work:

```
for f in `ls *.xml`; do mv $f `basename $f`_R.xml; done
```

Comment: A little description of this solution wouldn't hurt